# tmux strange characters in ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, windows-10, tmux

I just installed bash of ubuntu on windows 10 (Windows subsysexit
tem for linux) and tried use tmux on it.

But the separator character of panels is strange.
This separator has occupied 3 columns on space of shell and you can't see the initial character of commands.

Someone had this problem ?

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: First, welcome to SO. Have a look [here](http://superuser.com/q/1108443/553359). It looks like the font you're using has some issues.

Comment: @LaurIvan Thank you for this link.
My problem wasn't exactly that, but it helped me a lot.
I changed font to Consolas and it worked now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (not with tmux, but very similar). In my case it was a combination of 2 issues:

1. My default locale (on Ubuntu) wasn't English. Check your LANG environment variable. If it's not set to "en_US.UTF-8" there's a good chance you've got the same issue. You can change your default locale on Ubuntu using the following command:

   sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
2. The font I had for the bash window wasn't ready for displaying that non-English locale I had. You can change your font by opening the pull-down menu from the bash window title bar. Under the Fonts tab, try selecting some other font (in my case, Courier-New did the job vs. Consolas which didn't).